# Version upgrade issue of react-scripts v4-> v5 and craco v6 -> v7

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts, craco

In existing project we were trying to upgrade react-scripts from V4.0.3 => V5.0.1. After upgrade, Craco also need upgradation, so we have upgraded Craco V6.1.2 => V7.0.0. It creating issue with webpack-modernizr-loader. webpack-dev-server also not working. Below i have mentioned errors which i am facing.

```
node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/plugin-utils.js:26
throw new Error("".concat(message, "\n\n") +
^

Error: failed to add webpack-modernizr-loader

This error probably occurred because you updated react-scripts or craco. Please try updating craco to the latest version:

$ yarn upgrade craco

Or:

$ npm update craco

If that doesn't work, craco needs to be fixed to support the latest version.
Please check to see if there's already an issue in the gsoft-inc/craco repo:

https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues?q=is%3Aissue+webpack
If not, please open an issue and we'll take a look. (Or you can send a PR!)

You might also want to look for related issues in the craco and create-react-app repos:

https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues?q=is%3Aissue+webpack
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues?q=is%3Aissue+webpack
at throwUnexpectedConfigError (/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/plugin-utils.js:26:11)
at throwError (/client/craco.config.js:6:5)
at configure (/client/craco.config.js:52:40)
at giveTotalControl (/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/features/webpack/merge-webpack-config.js:76:25)
at mergeWebpackConfig (/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/features/webpack/merge-webpack-config.js:116:38)
at overrideWebpackDev (/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/features/webpack/override.js:8:80)
at //node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/scripts/start.js:21:39
npm ERR! Lifecycle script start-local failed with error:
npm ERR! Error: command failed
npm ERR! in workspace: client@1.0.0
npm ERR! at location: /client
```

Warning for Https & Middleware. Unable to resolve from config options.
[waring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXScU.png)

**Craco Config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const { addBeforeLoader, loaderByName, throwUnexpectedConfigError } = require('@craco/craco');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const throwError = (message) =>
  throwUnexpectedConfigError({
      packageName: 'craco',
      githubRepo: 'gsoft-inc/craco',
      message,
      githubIssueQuery: 'webpack',
  });

  module.exports = () => {
    const plugins = [];

    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    //   plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
    // }

    return {
      eslint: {
        enable: true,
      },
      style: {
        css: {
          loaderOptions: {
            modules: { localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]' },
          },
        },
      },
      webpack: {
        alias: {
          react: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules', 'react'),
          'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules', 'react-dom'),
          'modernizr': path.resolve(__dirname, "./.modernizrrc.js")
        },
        plugins,
        configure: webpackConfig => {
          // Adding modernizr loader Start
          const modernizrLoader = {
            loader: "webpack-modernizr-loader",
            test: /\.modernizrrc\.js$/,
          };

          const { isAdded: modernizrLoaderIsAdded } = addBeforeLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('url-loader'), modernizrLoader);
          if (!modernizrLoaderIsAdded) throwError('failed to add webpack-modernizr-loader');
          // Adding modernizr loader End

          const scopePluginIndex = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
            ({ constructor }) => constructor && constructor.name === 'ModuleScopePlugin'
          );
          
          const [ clientSrc ] = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins[scopePluginIndex].appSrcs;
          const psvServices = path.resolve(clientSrc,'../..');

          webpackConfig.resolve.plugins[scopePluginIndex].appSrcs.push(psvServices);

          return webpackConfig;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Tried to upgrade craco with react-scripts to latest versions. It's not working for me. Application is breaking by upgradation. Craco config style object not configuring properly, haviny issue with webpack-modernizr-loader.

**Project dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.4.3",
    "@instana/collector": "^1.129.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.29.0",
    "apollo-errors": "^1.9.0",
    "apollo-server-koa": "^1.3.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.281.1",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "basic-auth": "^2.0.0",
    "blocked": "^1.3.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cls-hooked": "^4.2.2",
    "consul": "^0.34.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.9",
    "date-fns": "^2.11.1",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "draft-js": "0.10.4",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.3.3",
    "draft-js-plugins-editor": "^2.1.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "element-scroll-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "fetch-timeout": "^0.0.2",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "form-data": "^2.3.2",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^3.0.5",
    "hare-niemeyer": "^2.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "humps": "^2.0.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "joi": "^17.6.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "koa": "^2.5.2",
    "koa-body": "^4.0.4",
    "koa-bunyan-logger": "^2.1.0",
    "koa-compress": "^3.0.0",
    "koa-convert": "^1.2.0",
    "koa-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "koa-cors": "0.0.16",
    "koa-json": "^2.0.2",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "koa-validate": "^1.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "memoize-one": "^5.1.1",
    "merge-graphql-schemas": "^1.5.1",
    "modernizr": "^3.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "mutation-observer": "^1.0.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "npm-link-shared": "^0.5.6",
    "oauth-1.0a": "^2.2.4",
    "object-hash": "^1.3.1",
    "openapi-request-validator": "^10.0.0",
    "openapi-response-validator": "^10.0.0",
    "openapi-schema-validator": "^10.0.0",
    "parse-domain": "^2.1.6",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-format": "^1.0.4",
    "pg-pool": "^3.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "puresql": "^1.8.0",
    "query-string": "5",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-aria-live": "^2.0.5",
    "react-card-flip": "^1.0.11",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.1.10",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dotdotdot": "^1.2.3",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.13",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.18.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-lazyload": "^2.6.2",
    "react-media": "^1.8.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.5.1",
    "react-paginate": "^6.2.1",
    "react-popper": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.10",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.87",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-tabs": "^2.2.2",
    "react-timeout": "^1.1.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.11.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.21.0",
    "reactable": "1.0.0",
    "recharts": "^2.1.15",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "redux-localstorage": "^0.4.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "swagger2-koa": "^1.0.2",
    "text-encoding": "^0.6.4",
    "uglify-js": "^3.13.3",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3",
    "use-resize-observer": "^6.1.0-alpha.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validate.js": "^0.12.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.4.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^2.4.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10",
    "command-line-args": "^5.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^6.3.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "cypress-failed-log": "^2.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "hygen": "^6.2.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-junit": "^1.5.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lerna": "^5.4.0",
    "local-ssl-proxy": "^1.3.0",
    "madge": "^5.0.1",
    "markdown-it": "^13.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "path-to-regexp": "^2.2.1",
    "pixrem": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.14",
    "postcss-apply": "^0.12.0",
    "postcss-calc": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^8.0.10",
    "postcss-custom-selectors": "^5.1.2",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-media-minmax": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-matches": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-not": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "should": "^13.2.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^19.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "wait-for-expect": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2"
  },
```